# Error in making line graph of recruitment for research study by month in r

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have a data frame with one column of id's and another of recruitment date and time in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".

I want to make a line graph of recruitment over time grouped by month.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(zoo) 

recruitment %>%
    count(as.yearmon(recruitment$date)) %>%
    mutate(cum_count = cumsum(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(as.yearmon(recruitment$date), cum_count)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_yearmon()
```

I'm getting an error:

> error in UseMethod(as.quoted):
> No applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "yearmon"

Comment: Have you attached the `plyr` package *after* attaching `dplyr`? When doing so I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: And generally don't use `data$column` inside `dplyr` functions like `count()`. Do `recruitment %>% count(as.yearmon(date))` not `recruitment %>% count(as.yearmon(recruitment$date))`. In this case I don't think it will make a difference, but it's a bad habit that will cause problems when you use `group_by()`

Comment: Gregor Thomas I tried that but that didn't work either. It says that the object date wasn't found which is why I did recruitment$date

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output from `dput(head(recruitment, 20))`? It will help give people a clearer idea of your dataset.